# geomintersect function

Tags: qgis, geometry, fields-attributes, expression

I am using `geomintersect` code in QGIS to only retrieve a target field from a target point layer if the target point layer intersects with the start point or endpoint of the line layer. or Vice versa (retrieving a target field from a target line layer if only the start point or endpoint intersects with the point layer).

I tried to use this function `startpoint(geomintersects('targetLayer','targetField'))` but I got no result.

what is the most recommended function to retrieve a field when only a point intersects a start or endpoint of a line?

Answer (score 4):

You can not do this directly using fieldcalculator and expressions, unfortunately. This is because you can not tell `geomintersects()` to be something else than the geometry itself, like a `start_point` of this geometry. You could only get the geometry of the intersecting point this way, by using `intersection(start_point($geometry),geom_from_wkt(geomintersects('pointlayer','$geometry')))`, but there is no chance to get a value of another layer by `intersects()`, `intersection()` or `geomintersects()`. You can only get its geometry. Therefore `get_feature()` or `get_feature_by_id()` cannot be used.

---

So you need to use a workaround. One could be to build a **virtual layer**, like this:

```
select linelayer.lineid, pointlayer.id, pointlayer.geometry from linelayer, pointlayer where st_intersects(st_startpoint(linelayer.geometry), pointlayer.geometry)
```

In this example I create a new pointlayer with the geometry of the intersecting points of the pointlayer with startpoints of the linelayer having attributes from both, the pointlayer and the linelayer. Of course you could also make this virtual layer a line, by using

```
select linelayer.lineid, pointlayer.id, linelayer.geometry from linelayer, pointlayer where st_intersects(st_startpoint(linelayer.geometry), pointlayer.geometry)
```

instead.

A great advantage of virtual layers is, that they get updated automatically if you change your point- or polygonlayer.